How to get id of option passed into Autocomplete as default value, which in turn is option's label?
I am trying to build a form based on DataGrid row object, which contains labels and corresponding them default values of form's inputs.
row = {label1: defaultValue1, label2: defaultValue2}

const { control } = useForm<MyForm>({
    defaultValues: { ...row },
  });

Then I am setting default value in Autocomplete's value prop by filtering options based on field.value prop which in turn is prop of render function prop of <Controller /> component.
<Controller
      name={name}
      control={control}
      render={({ field: { name, onChange, value } }) => (
        <Autocomplete
          options={options}
          value={options.find((o) => o.label === value || o.id === value) || null}
          renderInput={(params) => <TextField {...params} label={name} />}
          onChange={(_, selectedOption) => {
            const id = selectedOption?.id || null;
            onChange(id);
          }}
          
        />
      )}
    />

In the end, I am getting form's data as data attr of handleSubmit React Hook Form function.
const onSubmit: SubmitHandler<MyForm> = (data) => {...};

So, I need to get ids of options in this data attr. And if I will change Autocomplete in form, I will get it right, because of my onChange function. But if I will submit form without any changes, I will get labels set as default values.
Passing ids instead of labels as default values is problematic to me, because I get it from DataGrid, which contains only labels. Is it any way to convert set by default labels in ids in Autocomplete directly, may be based on options array given to it?
Thanks.
